# No logro que se muestren dos imágenes

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un juego con HTML, CSS y JavaScript, que consiste en seleccionar pares de imágenes iguales, aún queda mucho por hacer, pero la función que es el juego en sí no me funciona correctamente.

La idea es que al seleccionar dos imágenes, si son iguales de momento solo incremente un contador, y si no, que las vuelva a poner en negro, pero al seleccionar una si selecciona otra la que seleccione antes se pone en negro.

Este es el código:

```
var jugar = function () {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  var contador = 0;//Tiene que llegar a 10 para que el juego acabe
  var peon = null;//Aqui guardo la ultima imagen volteada que aun lo esta
  list.forEach(function (imagen) {
    imagen.addEventListener('click', function () {
      imagen.style.filter = 'none';
      if (peon == null) {
        peon = imagen;//Ya se cual es la ultima seleccionada
      }
      else {
        if (peon === imagen) {
          contador++;
        }
        else {
          peon.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
          imagen.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
          peon = null;
        }
      }
    });
    if (contador == 10) {
      alert("Juego completado");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hola Enmanuel, podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el HTML relacionado?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema con la igualdad de las imagenes. Tus imagenes son objetos y 2 objetos son iguales si comparten el mismo espacio en memoria, por lo que esto

```
if (peon === imagen)
```

Solo se cumple si es exactamente el mismo objeto.

Dicho de otro modo, dos objetos del tipo `img` **NO** son iguales aunque en pantalla muestren la misma imagen.

Lo que puedes hacer es comparar el atributo `src`

```
if (peon.src == imagen.src){
  contador++;
}
```